# SQL bulk insert CSV syntax error?

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to load up a simple CSV file using [this tutorial](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/). My CSV includes the list of nationalities, of which here is a sample:

`1,Afghan,2015-10-14 17:56:39`

Meanwhile, my table definitions is:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| ID          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| Nationality | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| Time        | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I'm running the following command:

`BULK INSERT meta_nationality FROM '/home/benjamin/Downloads/Nationalities.csv' WITH (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator ='\n');`

This seems to be right, however I get an error message pointing to a syntax issue:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bulk insert...`

[According to the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) the syntax error refers to the use of a reserved word, but I wouldn't know which one it is in this case.

Could you help me figure out my way through this? Thanks.

Comment: The tutorial you're following is for SQL Server, not MySQL.  Syntax differs significantly between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MySQL you'll want to use a different syntax. You should be aware that the tutorial you're following is for MSSQL.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/benjamin/Downloads/Nationalities.csv"
INTO TABLE meta_nationality
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

`BULK INSERT` isn't a command.

You were probably looking for [`LOAD DATA INFILE _____ INTO TABLE _____`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer MySQL tutorials instead of SQL server.
    LOAD DATA INFILE 
command will help you